# Why posting wrong chars with FTPUpload in an asp.net class (vb)?

Tags: encoding, ftpwebrequest

I m using that class to upload somes images with FTP from one server to another:

```
    Protected Sub FTPUpload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ftp As String = "ftp://IPSERVER"
    Dim login As String = "ftplogin"
    Dim Mpass As String = "ftpmpass"

    Dim ftpFolder As String = "serverpath"

    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = Nothing
    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName)
    Using fileStream As New StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
        fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileStream.ReadToEnd())
        fileStream.Close()
    End Using

    Try
        Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(ftp & ftpFolder & fileName), FtpWebRequest)
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(login, Mpass)
        request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length
        request.UsePassive = True
        request.UseBinary = True
        request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = fileBytes.Length
        request.EnableSsl = False

        Using requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)
            requestStream.Close()
        End Using

        Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

        lblMessage.Text &= fileName & " uploaded.<br />"
        response.Close()
    Catch ex As WebException
        Throw New Exception(TryCast(ex.Response, FtpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
    End Try
End Sub
```

the ftp works, but when i check the resut, the original file which began with :

```
IHDR   Ô   ˜   «š7=   TPLTEGpLí…ÞÌÍãÜÜñº¼Û (øððè +ýúúôäåÁ‹Ò¹¹ðž øÒÓÎ
```

will be returned in ftp like that :

```
IHDR   �   �   ��7=   TPLTEGpL큅�������� (���� +���������ҹ������
```

Please, where im wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

its Ok . i don't need to do any UTF encoding, Just grab the bytes.

```
fileStream = ImageUpload.PostedFile.InputStream
Dim fileBytes(0 to fileStream.Length - 1) as Byte
fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)
fileStream.Close()
```